# Display help icon to show portlet HELP MODE on Liferay

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet, jsr286

I'm trying to have a sample `Liferay` `portlet` that displays some dummy text under `HELP MODE`.

In my portlet.xml file (relevant part) :

```xml
<supports>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    <portlet-mode>help</portlet-mode>
    <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
</supports>
```

In my class that extends `GenericPortlet` (relevant) :

```java
@Override
protected void doHelp(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException
{
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write("Do Help");
}
```

However, When I launch my portlet under Liferay, I can't figure why **there is no help icon displayed**.

[image]

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Works for me. I have the same configuration in portlet.xml and I see "Help" menu item. Try to redeploy the portlet and refresh the page :) But, I use MVC-Portlet.

Comment: @Mark Thank you, I restarted the server and everything is okay now. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Restarting the server** did the trick... redeploying didn't work.

Probably some cache issues